# Lua popen with string arguments

Tags: lua

I am attempting to use popen to pipe a string containing multiple quotes to netcat. I have a Python command that works fine but I am turning it into an nmap script. I am not as familiar with Lua.

Python version:

```
python -c 'print "\x1b%-12345X@PJL FSDIRLIST NAME=\"0:\\..\\..\\..\\\" ENTRY=1 COUNT=999999\x0d\x0a\x1b%-12345X\x0d\x0a"' | nc 192.168.0.1 9100
```

Lua attempted version:

```
local handle = assert(io.popen("python -c 'print \"\x1b%-12345X@PJL FSDIRLIST NAME=\"0:\\..\\..\\..\\\" ENTRY=1 COUNT=999999\x0d\x0a\x1b%-12345X\x0d\x0a\"' | nc " .. host .. " " .. port, "r"))
```

This results in the following error:

```
File "<string>", line 1
    print "2345X@PJL FSDIRLIST NAME="0:\..\..\..\" ENTRY=1 COUNT=999999
```

Is there a way to organize that string so that Lua will accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a long string

```
[[python -c 'print "\x1b%-12345X@PJL FSDIRLIST NAME=\"0:\\..\\..\\..\\\" ENTRY=1 COUNT=999999\x0d\x0a\x1b%-12345X\x0d\x0a"' | nc 192.168.0.1 9100]]
```

Comment: I tried that out and got the error `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`. This occurs on the last double quote `print \"\x1b%-12345X@PJL FSDIRLIST NAME=\"0:\\..\\..\\..\\\" ENTRY=1 COUNT=999999\x0d\x0a\x1b%-12345X
[11] 0:bash*                                                                                              \x0d\x0a\"`. I tried escaping the single quotes in the string but that results in an `EOL while scanning string literal` error.

Comment: I removed the escape characters from the double quotes, single quotes, and percent signs. This works now. Thanks!